# Risk field with blank value for many alerts in OWASP ZAP alert details

Tags: security, owasp, zap, websecurity

Could someone please suggest why **Risk** data is **blank** for many alerts in OWASP **ZAP** alert details available at following ZAP official site:

https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/alerts/

For example -

```
Id      Alert                                                               Risk

10011   Cookie Without Secure Flag                                          Low
10009   In Page Banner Information Leak
10015   Incomplete or No Cache-control and Pragma HTTP Header Set
10017   Cross-Domain JavaScript Source File Inclusion
10019   Content-Type Header Missing
10020   X-Frame-Options Header
10020-1 X-Frame-Options Header Not Set                                      Medium
```

How, in such cases, risk or severity should be defined. Should it be based on whether risk is applicable for a specific web application.

Also, for some alerts, in the ZAP reports, **Risk** is populated as for example **Low(Medium)**. Should it be considered as Low or medium.

Answer (score 0):

That documentation is still a work in progress. Some scan rules raise multiple alerts (at different risks). The active and passive scan rules have different default methods/values. The team is working to address both situations in the scan rules and by association the alert description docs.

The `Low(Medium)` is Risk(Confidence). (Not risk and risk.)